# Make copies of div with unique elements and move each to separate div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make copies of a div with some unique prepended user-entered data, and to display each one in a new area.

For example: user enters a coupon code, clicks a button and a hidden, pre-formatted response appears in a div with their coupon code. I want to make sure an entire NEW pre-formatted response with unique coupon gets added to the div.

What i have so far is the new response gets appended but each new coupon code will be added to a single cloned response div, not a new response div. I know there's a much better way to do this, and one that WORKS too.

So how to I get **separate entries** to appear in the promo-applied-div, each having a unique promo code the user enters?

**The Markup**

```
  <input class="apply-promo-form" type="text">
  <button class="button">Click</button><br> 

  <div class="promo-applied-area">
    <!-- the promo applied div is revealed here on click -->
  </div>

  <div class="promo-info-div"> 
  <!-- the user's coupon code goes here --> <a class="view-details" href="#">view details</a> <span class="close">x</span>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.promo-applied-area {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.promo-info-div {
  display: none;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.close {
  cursor:pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**The jQuery**

```
$(function(){ 
  var pushIt = $('.promo-info-div');
  $('.button').click(function(){
    couponCode = $('.apply-promo-form').val();
    $('.promo-info-div').css('display','block');
    $('.promo-info-div').prepend(couponCode).clone();
    $('.promo-applied-area').prepend(pushIt);
    $('.apply-promo-form').val('');
  });

  $('.close').click(function(){
    $('.promo-info-div').slideUp();
  });
});
```

**[Here's my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkanup2n/1/)**

Comment: I'm sortof following. What is your question/problem? Good question are written in... you know... question form.

Comment: The problem is I'm not getting separate entries to appear in the promo-applied-div, each with the user's unique promo code. I'll update my question so it's more of a question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in your markup:

1. Use `id` when appropriate. You are using `class` everywhere instead. This is a problem because your statements like `$('.apply-promo-form').val()` will pick up first jQuery object if there are more than one element with the same class. Use `class` when you need to style and group elements together. Use `id` when you have to uniquely qualify and element.
2. Use templates as far as possible.
3. You are prepending the *couponCode* and then `.clone`ing it, but not using the cloned object anywhere. Regardless, this is not required.
4. `pushIt = $('.promo-info-div')` and then later `$('.promo-applied-area').prepend(pushIt)`? Prepending the same set of elements?

Here is a very crude example of what you could start with:

```js
$('.button').click(function () {
    var couponCode, templateHtml, $template, $span;

    template = $('#template').html(); // get the html out of template
    $template = $(template);          // convert that to a jQuery object
    $span = $("<span>");              // create a span to hold the coupon code
  
    couponCode = $('#apply-promo-form').val();  // get value of input into couponCode
  
    $span.text(couponCode);    // Add the couponCode text to the span
    $template.prepend($span);  // Prepend the span to the templated object
  
    // prepend the templated object to the area and show it
    $template.prependTo("#promo-applied-area").slideDown();
  
    // clear the form
    $('#apply-promo-form').val('');
});


// Event delegation required here, 
// because these are newly created elements
$('#promo-applied-area').on("click", ".close", function () {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(function() { 
        $(this).remove(); // Remove from DOM, no use for lingering objects
    }) 
});
```

```css
#promo-applied-area { height: 100px; padding: 5px; background: lightblue; }
.promo-info-div { display: none; background: lightgreen; }
.close { cursor:pointer; padding: 0 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="apply-promo-form" type="text">
<button class="button">Click</button><br/><br/>
<div id="promo-applied-area"></div>

<!-- This is defining a template -->
<script id="template" type="text/template">
    <div class="promo-info-div">
        <a class="view-details" href="#">View detail</a>
        <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know about that JS templating. Really cool. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

just change the placement of the append. you need to append the entire line of code, not just the coupons code.

DEMO 
http://jsfiddle.net/dkanup2n/6/

```
$(".button").on("click", function() {
var code = $('.apply-promo-form').val();
var info = $('.promo-info-div');
info.append('<a class="view-details" href="#">view details</a>'+code+'<span   class="close">x</span>');
});
```

Comment: This works, but I didn't accept it because I'd rather not inject HTML into my JS. Not a big deal, just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something more like this to get the order correct:

$('.promo-applied-area').prepend(pushIt.clone().prepend(couponCode));

and delete the "$('.promo-applied-div').prepend(couponCode);" line.

--edit--

Also, you could do the CSS after the clone() so you don't have the line displaying at the bottom:

$('.promo-applied-area').prepend(pushIt.clone().css('display', 'block').prepend(couponCode));